# Still On Ubuntu 20.04.2 Although 20.04.4 Released

Tags: 20.04, updates

I don't have any gripes about my Ubuntu installation, it works fine.

Lately I saw that 7 Python updates couldn't be installed - each update was prefixed with the Ubuntu version 20.04.4. I checked the installed version of my Ubuntu and it is 20.04.2.

It seems that Ubuntu 20.04.4 is out since March 2022 but my updater for some reason is not including it.

```
~$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:printing-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for sandbar: 
Hit:1 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable InRelease                
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/blaze/rtbth-dkms/ubuntu focal InRelease         
Hit:4 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease               
Hit:6 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Hit:7 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                
Hit:8 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease           
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease          
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kisak/kisak-mesa/ubuntu focal InRelease        
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu focal InRelease      
Hit:13 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lyzardking/ubuntu-make/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mkusb/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/slyon/iwd+nm/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/swi-prolog/stable/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurora/ubuntu focal InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up-to-date.
~$
```

Why is my machine being left out of the update loop ?

**Machine:** Dell Inspiron 15 5000 Series

**CPU:** i5-7xxx

**RAM:** 16GB

**GPU:** AMD Radeon R7 M445

[image][image]

**Post-Installation of 20.04.4 APT Sources List**

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20200731)]/ focal main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
# deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
# deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
# deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
# deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
# deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates focal-updates restricted deb-src multiverse main universe http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates focal-updates restricted deb-src multiverse main universe http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
```

[image]

Comment: Open Software & Update and make sure all the repositories are ticked.

Comment: All repositories ? Source repos too ? Why ?

Comment: Only guessing: You have several PPAs enabled. Could it be that you have installed a program package from one PPA, that has dependencies, that will not allow further upgrades? But maybe, if you install the `synaptic` program package, it will help you get the `focal-updates` pocket of the Ubuntu repositories. Otherwise please tell us, and (let us hope) somebody can help you do it via the command line.

Comment: Synaptic doesn't show focal, let alone focal-updates. But it's fixed now and 20.04.4 is in the machine.

Answer (score 9):

You are missing the `focal-updates` pocket of the Ubuntu repositories. That's why your system is running 20.04.2.

The several errors in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file suggest that somebody made mistakes while hand-editing the file.

1. Add the following line to that file:

```
deb http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted multiverse
```

2. Delete the badly formatted line from that file:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates focal-updates restricted deb-src multiverse main universe http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
```

3. Run `sudo apt update`.

This will fix the question you asked about: Your system will be able to detect updates to 20.04.4 and beyond. It won't fix the other problems you created by adding dead/obsolete PPAs that might still block those updates from being installed.

Comment: There is NO option to do so on Software & Updates. See screenshot in OP. Also see Sources List file after finding 20.04.4 installed following checking 'source' as well as 'main' repos and accepting a set of updates offered. I don't see why focal-updates isn't given a separate repo entry on S&U > Other Software if this is needed to maintain current releases. And I don't see why checking the 'source' repos should make any difference. I thought 'source' repos were for only people who wanted to build their own installations.

Comment: Edited to address your comment. Hope it helps.

Comment: No hand-editing was done. But there is some error when transferring edits from the Software & Updates GUI. That looks like it to me. Suggestions done.